# SQL query : how to select records which all records in related table have specific value of attribute

Tags: sql

Given an example table definition:

```
school:
  school_id  |  school_name    
-------------+------------
     1       | school1
     2       | school2
     3       | school3

classroom:
classroom_id | has_projector | school_id      
-------------+---------------+-------------
     1       |     f         | 1
     2       |     f         | 1
     1       |     t         | 2
     2       |     t         | 2
     1       |     f         | 3
     2       |     t         | 3
     3       |     t         | 3
```

How to select schools which all classrooms have projector?
(In this case only school2 schould be selected.)

My idea is :

```
select school_name from school where 
school_id in (select school_id from classroom where has_projector='t') and 
school_id not in (select school_id from classroom where has_projector!='t');
```

It works, but is it an optimal solution?
Are there any better ways to select requested data?

Comment: Do you want a school without any class rooms at all to be returned?

Comment: No, only these ones with at least one classroom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think a simple aggregation with a `having` clause is a bit simpler:

```
select s.school_id
from school s join
     classroom c
     on s.school_id = c.school_id
group by s.school_id
having sum(case when has_projector = 't' then 1 else 0 end) = count(*);
```

Answer (score 1):

Left join school to classroom on the school id and has projector equal to false. Then only return the ones where the school id on the classroom table is null.

```
    SELECT school_name
    FROM school
    LEFT JOIN classroom
    ON school.school_id = classroom.school_id
    AND classroom.has_projector = 'f'
    WHERE classroom.school_id IS NULL
```

Comment: I like this better than the COUNT approach

Comment: Note, that it will return all schools that don't have any classrooms as well.

Comment: That is true, it returns also schools with no classrom at all. I don't need them.

Comment: I guess my assumption was that if there's a school, it has to have at least one classroom. In this case, you'll want to use Gordon's solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
    select distinct s.school_name
    from school s, classroom c
    where s.school_id = c.school_id
    and c.has_projector = 't'
```

This is about as simple as it can be written.

CK

Comment: It selects schools with at least one classroom with projector. Not schools which all classrooms have projector.